# Gulp file integration with browsersync

Tags: javascript, gulp, synchronization

I've been trying to figure out how to get my current gulpfile to work with browsersync and I'm lost in the woods.

I set up my gulpfile by following this [tutorial](http://callmenick.com/post/an-introduction-to-gulp) which got my going with gulp.

The issue I'm experiencing is when I try to integrate browsersync with my gulp file. I've tried to figure out how to make my current gulpfile work with the SASS + CSS Injecting and reload features which are listed on the documentation for [browsersnyc + gulp.js](http://www.browsersync.io/docs/gulp/) but no luck.

Here is my current gulpfile that I have set up. 
At this point I'm really unsure how to get browsersnyc to work with the way I have my gulpfile running. Nothing seems to be working. How do I configure this the correct way?

Thank you

```
// refferance gulp
var gulp = require('gulp');

// refferance packages installed
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var cssmin = require('gulp-minify-css');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');
var scss = require('gulp-sass');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();

// build server
gulp.task('serve',['build'], function(event){
    browserSync({
        server: {
            baseDir:'./'
        }
    });
    // watch 
    gulp.watch(".//scss/*.scss", ['sass']);
    gulp.watch(".//*.html").on('change', browserSync.reload);
});


// set up default task we can use this later to run all of our tasks
gulp.task('default', function(){
    // our default task runs `scripts`, `styles` and `watch` when we enter `gulp` in command line.
    //  Only use this task once we have set up all our other tasks
    // gulp.task('default',['scripts','styles','watch']);
});


// scripts task
gulp.task('scripts', function(){
    // fetch all files in the .js extension in the /src/js directory
    return gulp.src('./src/js/*.js')
    // concatinate files and save as app.js
    .pipe(concat('app.js'))
    // save app.js in dest directory
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dest/js/'))
    .pipe(uglify())
    // minfiy file and rename to app.min.js
    .pipe(rename({
        suffix: '.min'
    }))
    // save in dest directory
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dest/js'));
});


// styles task
gulp.task('styles', function(){
     // fetch all files with scss extension in /src/scss directory
    return gulp.src('./src/scss/*.scss')
    // compile scss
    .pipe(scss())
    // output css in css dest directory
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dest/css/'))
    // minify css
    .pipe(cssmin())
    // rename as styles.min.css
    .pipe(rename({
        suffix: '.min'
    }))
    // save in same directory
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dest/css'))

    // once css compiles reload browser??
    .pipe(browserSync.stream());
});

// serve up changes??
gulp.task('default', ['serve']);

gulp.watch('./src/js/*.js', ['scripts']);
gulp.watch('./src/sass/*.scss', ['styles']);

// watch task
gulp.task('watch',function(){
    // watch js
    gulp.watch('./src/js/*.js',['scripts']);
    // watch scss
    gulp.watch('./src/scss/*.scss',['styles']);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

As far as I can see, you only execute the scss task for changes to Sass and do not reload browsersync. Try merging the watch statements into one. You can watch an array of file patterns so just combine scss and html.

Your server will not be started using browsersync. Try using nodemon instead if you want auto-restarts on changes. browsersync will only proxy your existing node process to another port on your system.

Furthermore, you have to install `browsersync` on your system:

```
npm install -g browser-sync
```

Comment: Can you please post an example @Darneas also how to I get the browser to fire up the server?

Comment: Your server will not be started using browsersync. Try using nodemon instead if you want auto-restarts on changes.

Comment: So you need to set up a sever separate to using browsersync?

Comment: I have forgotten to set up the server with browsersync. I need to first do that :) My bad..

Comment: Yes. Browsersync will only proxy your connection if you decide to do so, but will not start the server. How should it anyway? There is no way to specify the server file.

Comment: Correct! Turns out I forgot to `sudo npm install -g browser-sync`  to my machine. Missed the whole set up phase. I thought I could just run a few gulp tasks and it would fire up some server. But like you said there's no server file..My error : )

Comment: Well I was able to get it `html` to reload on change but no luck what so ever with css changes reloading. I've spent two day's trying to figure out why and nothing..Really annoying. I know there's just one line of code that's prob not set up right in my gulp file but I have no idea where that is. Feel free to check out my repo and see if you can figure out what's going on. https://github.com/kapena/portfolio_

Answer (score 1):

```
function watchFiles(isDev) {
   if (isDev) {
       gulp.watch([config.sass], ['styles', browserSync.reload]);
       gulp.watch([config.client + '**/*', '!' + config.sass], browserSync.reload)
           .on('change', function(event) { changeEvent(event); });
   }
   else {
       gulp.watch([config.sass, config.js, config.html], ['build', browserSync.reload])
           .on('change', function(event) { changeEvent(event); });
   }
}
```

Above is an example of how I watch files, and reload browser using browserSync on change.